# MFT performance with fragmented SSDs

Tags: ssd, ntfs

My undestanding is that NTFS's MFT maps file names with each physical location (or some kind of virtual address) of file fragments.
Therefore a highly fragmented disk such as a SDD will have a bigger MFT and that will incur a RAM penalty for loading the MFT as well as a CPU penalty for reading the MFT. Are these assumptions correct ?

EDIT [more info on the MFT content](https://whereismydata.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/file-system-mft-technical/)

> Each MFT entry is (as standard) 1024 bytes long, or 2 sectors, and
>   contains information about the file it references.
>
> This includes:
>
> -The file name
>
> -Directory the file belongs to
>
> -Dates: Created, Modified, Access, Entry modified – the last time the MFT entry was modified for that file
>
> -File Size
>
> -File permissions
>
> -**Physical location of the file**. This gives the location or locations of the file within NTFS file system on the hard drive.
>   Remember that a file within an NTFS system does not need to be
>   contiguous, and it can be split into different sections around the
>   hard drive. **All of those different sections are referenced within
>   the MFT entry**, in a section called “Index” or “Data”.

Comment: Why do you assume that SSDs are highly fragmented? This does not make sense. If you are referring to the SSD wear leveling - this is totally transparent (not detectable) by the OS.

Comment: well I run some defragmenter and it came up with a fragments count and a file count. I believe these come straight from the MFT

Comment: Running a defragmenter on a SSD is nonsense - it just decreases the life of the SSD (unnecessary write operations). The MFT manages the file fragments (nothing unusual) and it can self be fragmented. Defragmentation utilities usually count and correct the fragmented files, not of the MFT itself.

Comment: if the MFT manages the fragments and that there are many fragments because SSDs are never defragmented, does reading the MFT incur a performance penalty ?

Comment: Speaking bout performance penalties because of fragmentation when using a SSDs is like worrying about small blob of dirt on an airplane wing can decrease the speed the plane flies - you need a lot of it unless you even have a slightest impact.

Comment: please check this @Robert  https://www.hanselman.com/blog/therealandcompletestorydoeswindowsdefragmentyourssd.aspx

Comment: This blog article was written six years ago, and that's a lifetime in computer science. SSD manufacturers have made a lot of progress in both making their hardware and fine-tuning the firmware that makes them work. A 2020 3D-NAND SSD by Toshiba or Samsung doesn't offer the same level of performance as your basic 2014 SSD. What was considered as high-end firmware six years ago is now the norm, as new players have entered the field with more affordable, yet very efficient, products.

Comment: @Didier be more specific, because despite countless improvements to the HDD tech, defrag remained pretty much the same for 25 years.....

Comment: How more specific should I be? Nowadays, a 500GB SSD such as the one I have on my Lenovo laptop has an actual 550GB storage space, when you add all its memory chips, but due to overprovisioning, a big chunk of that space (often 10-12 %) is kept in reserve, to allow for the wear and tear that *will* happen over time, so defragmenting an SSD nowadays doesn't mean it'll break down on you in a matter of months. Same for the firmware, that usually maintains the SSD in tip-top shape no matter what, thanks to predictive algorithms based on your, and the OS, usage habits.